# Create a vector of object from another vector of string

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, functor

Suppose I have a vector of string that contains name and now I want to create a vector of Athlete class from this vector names. So how can I create one **without** using loop?

Here is my `Athlete` class:

```
class Athlete{
public:
     Athlete(string name, int number);

private:
     string name;
     int number, time;
};
```

Here is my attempt **using loop**, suppose vector names already contains some elements:

```
vector<string> names;
vector<Athlete> athletes;

for(auto i = names.begin(); i != names.end(); i++)
    athletes.push_back(Athlete(*i, i - names.begin() + 1));
```

But now I want to create the vector athletes **without** using loop. At first, I thought I would use generate but then the function object cannot refer to the vector names. So which function should I use?

Comment: What a leak. Why not just `athletes.push_back(Athlete(*i, i - names.begin() + 1));`? Or `emplace_back`, whatever.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I haven't noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: You can always [`std::transform()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Lambda function

Still technically a loop, but multiple times uglier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Athlete {
public:
    Athlete(std::string name, int number) {};

private:
    std::string name;
    int number, time;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<Athlete> athletes;

    std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::back_inserter(athletes),
        [&names](std::string const& name)
        {
            return Athlete(name, &name - &names.front() + 1);
        });
}
```

---

## Range-based for loop

Funny, because the loop could have been:

```
for(auto const& name : names)
    athletes.emplace_back(name, &name - &names.front() + 1);
```

---

## Function object #1

But since you want a functor class, this is the definition:

```
class StringToAthleteFunct
{
    std::vector<std::string> const& names;

public:

    StringToAthleteFunct(std::vector<std::string> const& names) :
    names(names)
    {
    }

    Athlete operator()(std::string const& name) const
    {
        return Athlete(name, &name - &names.front() + 1);
    }
};
```

And this is usage:

```
std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::back_inserter(athletes),
    StringToAthleteFunct(names));
```

---

## Function object #2

Actually, this one is better:

```
class StringToAthleteFunct
{
    int index;

public:
    StringToAthleteFunct() : index(0) { }

    Athlete operator()(std::string const& name)
    {
        return Athlete(name, ++index);
    }
};
```

- does not require reference to the source vector

Comment: Thanks, ugly but working. But I am still think if there is anyway to use functor in this.

Comment: You want to go too far into the ugliness. Is this a reverse code review? LOL

Comment: Yes, I "have" to in this case.

Comment: Conversion from lambda to functor should be easy. But instead of capturing `&names`, you'll have to pass it as an argument. I'll add that into the answer.

Comment: “ugly” is relative. I prefer the loop-less algorithm: It’s less error-prone. Better yet would be to compose it with a stream of integers but that requires third-party library support (or re-implementing a boatload of Boost libraries).

Comment: Generally, I like the algorithmic approach, but look at the range-based for-loop here.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works like a charm. The index is much simpler now.